# NullReferenceException thrown when app is updated and new UI added - WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, nullreferenceexception

This is really strange and happening for the first time.

I have one version of the app in the store. The next version has few UI changes. A lot of re arrangements were made.

Now what happens is, for a textblock written in xaml I get a NullReferenceException when I try to assign some text. InitilizeComponent is called before I assign the value, so how does the textblock remain null!

```
                <Grid x:Name="AdsDialog" Grid.Row="2">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Name="statusPreview1" Text=" " Width="240" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF121212" FontFamily="{StaticResource CicleSemi}" MaxWidth="250" MaxHeight="70" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,3" />
                        <TextBlock Name="statusPreview" Text="" Width="240" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF121212" FontFamily="{StaticResource CicleSemi}" MaxWidth="250" MaxHeight="70" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,3" />
                    </StackPanel>    
                </Grid>
```

The error is gone when I rebuild the app. But most probably will throw exception if i push out an update for existing users!

StatusPreview1 is the new TextBlock.

Somebody please help!

Comment: It is possible that you moved it into some Template witch is not reachable

Answer (score 1):

While I can't really explain why you got this null exception in first place, your concerns are unfounded. After updating, the users will have the exact same binary content as you. Only data stored in the application storage can cause issues during an update.

Most likely, the compiler failed to notice some of your changes and didn't regenerate the files in the obj folder (did you change the system date of your computer by any chance?). When doing a full rebuild, the compiler stops trying to figure out which files need to be regenerated, and compiles everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by running it in the `Release` mode and not Debug mode, so I guess the previous version got over written or may the the missing things got updated and everything works!